# Intel HD 3000 Ubuntu 64-Bit 12.04, How to fix overscan?

Tags: 12.04, intel-graphics, hdmi, asus

I'm new to this but my problem is that I am trying to connect my Panasonic TC-L32X2 TV to my ASUS BD3MA Laptop through HDMI, because my xbox is occupying my VGA port, and even though it supports 1080p through the HDMI cable, it seems to be giving me Overscan and unlike in windows, I can't seem to find a way to scale the resolution to fit on the physical screen.

It seems to be cutting off all four edges if I could find a way to scale down the resolution to about 95% both vertical and horizontal then I believe that would solve my problem.

I am somewhat familiar with xRandr but not familiar with Xorg. There are no settings on my TV to adjust this even on the secret menus. My computer is running Intel HD3000 or sandy bridge gfx, integrated into my CPU. I'll post my xrandr output.

I've also tried to set my resolution using xrandr to lower resolutions even 720p but it only seems to cut off more of my screen when I do that.  Also my TV supports 16:9 and through VGA supports resolutions up to 1366x768 I don't know if that helps but thought I should mention it.

Sorry if my posting skills are not up to par the code was too long to screen-shot it.

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1848, maximum 8192 x 8192
LVDS1 connected 1366x768+554+1080 (0x45) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 344mm x 194mm
    Identifier: 0x41
    Timestamp:  1606552
    Subpixel:   horizontal rgb
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       1
    CRTCs:      1 0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff004ca34a3200000000
        00150103802213780ace859e5b4c9426
        17505400000001010101010101010101
        0101010101017d1e5618510016303020
        250058c2100000190000000f00000000
        00000000001eb4027400000000fe0053
        414d53554e470a2020202020000000fe
        00313536415432342d5030310a20001c
    BACKLIGHT: 10 (0x0000000a)  range:  (0,10)
    Backlight: 10 (0x0000000a)  range:  (0,10)
    scaling mode:   Full aspect
        supported: None         Full         Center       Full aspect 
  1366x768 (0x45)   78.0MHz -HSync -VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1366 start 1414 end 1446 total 1646 skew    0 clock   47.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  770 end  775 total  790           clock   60.0Hz
  1360x768 (0x46)   84.8MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1432 end 1568 total 1776 skew    0 clock   47.7KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  798           clock   59.8Hz
  1360x768 (0x47)   72.0MHz +HSync -VSync
        h: width  1360 start 1408 end 1440 total 1520 skew    0 clock   47.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  781 total  790           clock   60.0Hz
  1024x768 (0x48)   65.0MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock   48.4KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock   60.0Hz
  800x600 (0x49)   40.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock   37.9KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock   60.3Hz
  800x600 (0x4a)   36.0MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  824 end  896 total 1024 skew    0 clock   35.2KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  603 total  625           clock   56.2Hz
  640x480 (0x4b)   25.2MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock   31.5KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock   59.9Hz
VGA1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x42
    Timestamp:  1606552
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (0xcc) normal (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 698mm x 392mm
    Identifier: 0x43
    Timestamp:  1606552
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Gamma:      1.0:1.0:1.0
    Brightness: 1.0
    Clones:    
    CRTC:       0
    CRTCs:      1 0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    EDID:
        00ffffffffffff0034a906c301010101
        00140103800000780adaffa3584aa229
        17494b00000001010101010101010101
        010101010101023a801871382d40582c
        4500ba882100001e011d8018711c1620
        582c2500ba882100009e000000fc0050
        616e61736f6e69632d54560a000000fd
        00173d0f440f000a2020202020200150
        02031e71499005200403020706012309
        070167030c001000b82de3050301011d
        007251d01e206e285500ba882100001e
        8c0ad08a20e02d10103e9600ba882100
        00188c0ad08a20e02d10103e96000b88
        210000188c0aa01451f01600267c4300
        ba88210000988c0aa01451f01600267c
        43000b882100009800000000000000b5
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on          
  1920x1080 (0xcc)  148.5MHz +HSync +VSync *current +preferred
        h: width  1920 start 2008 end 2052 total 2200 skew    0 clock   67.5KHz
        v: height 1080 start 1084 end 1089 total 1125           clock   60.0Hz
  1280x720 (0xcd)   74.2MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1390 end 1430 total 1650 skew    0 clock   45.0KHz
        v: height  720 start  725 end  730 total  750           clock   60.0Hz
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
    Identifier: 0x44
    Timestamp:  1606552
    Subpixel:   unknown
    Clones:    
    CRTCs:      1 0
    Transform:  1.000000 0.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 1.000000 0.000000
                0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
               filter: 
    Broadcast RGB:  Full
        supported: Full         Limited 16:2
    audio:  auto
        supported: off          auto         on
```